# In Jyotish, is there a chain of predecessors in planetary realm?

Tags: astrology

I'm curious to know the following:

In panchabhutas, we all know, Akasha or ether gave birth to air. Air to water and so forth.

Likewise, is there any such planetary ascension/relationship between planets?

A friend suggests this partial sequence: Ketu->Mars->Sun->Saturn. Is this correct? If so, what is the rest in this relationship sequence?

Comment: Do you want to know only from Jyotishya??

Comment: @Destroyer, kindly share any and all kinds of knowledge you might have on the subject, need not be strictly jyotish.